# how to threat errors on spring cloud dataflow?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-dataflow

When deploying my microservice on spring cloud dataflow I get the following log:

`No bean named 'errorChannel' has been explicitly defined. Therefore, a default PublishSubscribeChannel will be created`

how do I direct error flows?

My guess is to create an errorChannel bean (as the message says). But I did not find any docs about it nor sample usages.

For example, I have a sink that executes an Insert on a database and want to direct it elsewhere if insert fails.

Answer (score 1):

The default `errorChannel` bean has a `LoggingHandler` subscribed to it.

If you define your own `errorHandler` channel, it won't get the default `LoggingHandler`.

The error channel is automatically wired in.

Each consumer (or `@StreamListener`) gets a dedicated error channel `binding.group.errors` which is bridged to the global `errorChannel`.

You can add a `@ServiceActivator` to consume `ErrorMessage`s from either of these channels.

Error channels are not applied on the producer side; you have to catch the exception yourself.